# Best way to copy specific result set from an Oracle database to an SQLite database in C++

Tags: c++, oracle, sqlite

I need to insert the rows of a result set I got from an Oracle database into a new table in an SQLite database. Currently, I create an insert statement from every row in the result set and execute it on the SQLite database. But it seems to me there must be a more direct way. Or bis this the way to go?

Comment: Do you mean one insert *in total* or one insert *for each row*? The former should be preferred in your case IMO, because it only needs one transaction.

Comment: I mean one insert for each row.  But that is not my point. I am kind of a noob to SQL. I wonder if there is a way without insert statements in general. Like: "here is my result set, please put this as table123 in the database"

Comment: I think it is the point! I'll write an answer which may help you... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't think **C++** plays any significant role here. You would very likely face exactly the same problems in Java, PHP, C or any other client language.

Second, a good solution will take into account **how big** the data is. Are we talking about, say, 1000 rows, or rather a few million ones? For "small" data, a solution where the whole transition happens entirely in memory may suffice. For "larger" data, you may have to resort to writing intermediate data on the disk.

Third, what about data integrity? Is it possible that the source database is **changed** while we are transferring it to the destination database? If not, then everything is easier as well.

All of that being said, here is an approach which may work: Use the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` syntax (if you insert into an existing table) or the `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT` (if you want to create a new table). Look at the SQLite documentation for [`INSERT`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html):

> The second form of the INSERT statement contains a SELECT statement
>   instead of a VALUES clause. A new entry is inserted into the table for
>   each row of data returned by executing the SELECT statement.

... or for [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html):

> A "CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT" statement creates and populates a
>   database table based on the results of a SELECT statement.

In both cases, the trick would be to create a `SELECT` statement which returns fixed values that actually come from the source database.

This means that in your C++ client application, you first make a `SELECT` statement in the source database and then use it to create either an `INSERT` or `CREATE TABLE` query string which will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table SELECT 1, "abc", 2 UNION SELECT 123, "def", 456 UNION SELECT 1000, "foo", 2000
```

... where all the values like 1, "abc", 2, 123, "def" and so on come from the source database and are used to build up the query in your C++ application.

The problem is that this does not scale well because of the many `UNION`s, and it makes it harder to use prepared statements (code-wise). But at least it's a one-statement approach.

All things considered, you may consider just keeping your current solution but use a [transaction](http://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) for all individual `INSERT`s. This will ensure that either all or none of the rows are inserted.

Comment: In my case the data isn't big and the integrity is also not an issue. So if I understand correctly, the key point is that you need to create  textual statements in any case and that there is no "direct" way without statements, right? I was imagining something where one could execute a statement on the source database (SQLite), get some pointer to the actual data and pass this pointer somehow (maybe through some converter library) to the destination database (Oracle), where it then gets integrated.

Comment: If such a direct way exists, then I'm certainly not aware of it. Different database management systems may use vastly different implementation techniques. In fact, even one and the same system may use different storage mechanisms in different situations. Typically, not even the SQL (i.e. the interface) they understand is 100% compatible, let alone the backend! And databases do not just consist of tables but also of views, triggers and other advanced mechanisms. Nevertheless... what's so bad about using textual statements anyway, and how is it more difficult than using some "converter library"?

Comment: You are certainly right that it's not difficult. It just seems to be an unnecessary overhead to convert data to text and back to data. Do you know if some of the database abstraction APIs, like ODBC, have a direct mechanism like passing cursors?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I'm by no means an expert on ODBC. However, IMO, that would just be a different kind of overhead.